# Google Analytics API - Client Side Auth with Service account

Tags: javascript, json, google-analytics-api

I'm wanting to make a Google Analytics dashboard for our company website so that marketing teams can see key website stats.  I'd like to use service account auth so that I don't have to manage permissions etc in google analytics

This will be hosted on our "intranet" on Sharepoint, which is locked away behind microsoft login.  I've created a read-only google account as the service account.  I know that there are some potential security pitfalls with client-side auth, but I'm not too worried since this a company site with login required.

Anyway, I'm not really sure where to start, I've been searching for hours and the closest I found was [this post here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136241/can-i-display-google-analytic-results-form-an-external-site-on-sharepoint/186748#186748), but I cant decipher the solution and I don't have enough cred over there to comment and ask them to explain further

I *think* I know I need the JSON key to generate a token, but I have no idea how to do that with JavaScript or even if this is the right track...

Comment: Key things to understand about a service account is that you need a place to run the service account (ie a server) the code will generate a token, you need to pass that token to the JavaScript Client, then the client can make an API request with the authenticated API access token. I do not know anything about sharepoint and I assume you've seen the open source [demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/).

Comment: You should also look into using [Google Data Studio](https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/) It makes creating and sharing dashboards easy.

Comment: Thanks Matt, the post I linked to above seemed to be able to use Javascript to generate the token client-side from what I can gather, its just a bit over my head - am hoping someone can breaking it down for me.  I'll also look into data studio, haven't really poked my nose in there yet.